# tinymce jquery version vs jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, tinymce

What is the difference between [tinymce jQuery **version**](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/jquery_version.php) and [tinymce jQuery **plugin**](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/jquery_plugin.php)? 
Are there any functionality differences? 
What are some criteria for deciding which one to use?

Answer (score 8):

One big difference is performance!

I found out that the internal handling of keystrokes (checks and functions) of the jquery tinymce build is 4 times slower than the handling in the regular tinymce build (`tiny_mce.js`). This had a big impact on a project i had been working on where performance was a crucial aspect and lots of addional checks and functions had to be added in order to press tinymce to the users desires. Now i use jQuery as library + the regular tinymce build -> works great.

Comment: just to be extra clear, when you say regular tinymce build, that's neither of the versions that I mentioned in the question, but just the regular tiny_mce.js? Which version were you using? Upvote for the interesting performance observation. I'd like to see what others have experienced as well.

Comment: oops, my fault. overread the question too fast. but yes the regular tiny_mce.js is slower than the jquery tinymce build

Comment: you mean the other way around?

Comment: @Thariama I've got totally confused. Tiny MCE Jquery version OR Tiny MCE Jquery Plugin, which one is slower ?

Comment: the "Tiny MCE Jquery version" is slower. i guess the reason for this is the necesssary jQuery object creation overhead for many tasks

Comment: I hate to beat a dead horse, but it is important I understand this explicitly.  @Thariama when I look at the jQuery site, there is a TinyMCE 4.0b1 "Production" package and there is a TinyMCE 4.0b1 jquery package which includes the jQuery plugin.  Your observations show that the TinyMCE 4.0b1 jQuery Package is slower than using the regular production package?  So we would see a performace hit using the jQuery Plugin over using the regular package on top of our already loaded jQuery library?

Comment: @Shawn: yes, at least i has been several minor versions before. the tinymce jQuery build does not contain the regular jQuery lib, but offers methods to access and treat a tinymce editor jQuery likewise. Users may not encounter any problems at all (depending on the user machine), but in case many plugins are involved and there is much code being executed on several key events then the user may encounter its disadvantages (while typing in letters). I mean its logical: Creating objects for all kind of operations is overhead if there is a solution that addresses an issue the direct way.

Comment: @Thariama, Have you confirmed those numbers (eg 4 times slower) for the latest version(current 3.5.8 or the 4.0 beta)?  How were you able to test the performance?  I need to verify for myself.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: The tests we have performed were for tinymce version 3.2 or 3.4 . We had several tinymce plugins that did many things on several KeyEvents. The performance was measured using console.time() (which is not the 100% perfect tool, but gives some helpfull indications)

Comment: Is this the issue with 4.0 or higher?

Comment: due to the object creation overhead (using jQuery) we may assume this will be the case with tinymce 4.x too

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the tinymce jQuery version is just a bit smaller than the "normal" version, because they use the libraries which are redundant with jquery directly from jquery.

So there shouldn't be any differences between the jquery version and the "normal" version.

The jquery plugin on the other hand lets you do things like this:

```
$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce();
```

So if you intend to use the jquery plugin you are most propably save to use the tinymce jquery version.